# How can I make cupcakes lighter?

Tags: cupcakes

I'm a new baker and I've had some pretty decent cupcakes but I feel that they are more thicker then wanted. What can I do to make them lighter?
[image]

Comment: Welcome! I've removed your general request for help because here we like to focus on specific topics so asking for general advice is out of our scope.  To help us out, can you please let us know the recipe and method for your cupcakes? Without it, we won't be able to tell you what to change to improve them.

Comment: Yes of course I'm sorry it didn't come to mind

Comment: You might want to consider the recipe you're using.  I'd consider going with the approach of chiffon cake.  Whip the egg whites, and then fold them into the rest of the batter.  (you'd mix the yolks in when it calls for the eggs, but it looks like yours calls for whites only)

Comment: And the best advice for baking : get an oven thermometer.  You'd be amazed at how much ovens can vary from what the dial says.

Comment: I am not sure I understood what do you mean by "lighter", especially when contrasted to "thicker". Do you mean you have too few holes in your crumb (they are too dense), or something else?

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is you are probably over mixing the batter. When you over mix, gluten networks develop leading to a denser and chewier texture.

You should mix the batter until "just combined" which just means until you can no longer see the ingredient you just added.

[image: Oversized Cupcake]

http://www.cupcakeproject.com/2014/05/what-happens-when-you-overmix-cake-batter.html

Comment: If they want to show real problems w/ over mixing, you have to cut it open.  you'll have this strange tunneling, where bubbles tried to escape but got trapped by the gluten.  It looks like insects have been crawling through.  (it happens most often w/ muffins)